# Unable to signup users with passport-local

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js, passport.js

I'm trying to use a local passport to login and signup in my app.

But when I send a post request from my signup form, the user is being redirected to the signup form.

This is the route definition:

```
app.post('/signup', passport.authenticate('local-signup', {
        successRedirect : '/profile', // redirect to the secure profile section
        failureRedirect : '/signup', // redirect back to the signup page if there is an error
        failureFlash : true // allow flash messages
    }));
```

This is my config/passport.js

```
var LocalStrategy   = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var User            = require('../models/user');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : process.env.MYSQL_HOST,
  user     : process.env.MYSQL_USER,
  password : process.env.MYSQL_PASSWORD,
  database : process.env.MYSQL_DB
});

module.exports = function(passport) {
    passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
        console.log("abc serializeUser");
        console.log(user);
        done(null, user.id);
    });

    passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
        console.log("abc deserializeUser");
        User.findById(id).then(function(user){
            done(null, user);
        }).catch(function(e){
            done(e, false);
        });
    });

    passport.use('local-signup', new LocalStrategy(

        function(username, password, done) {
            console.log("abc local signup");
            User.findOne({where: {username: username}}).then(function(err, user) {
               if (err) { return done(err); }
               if (!user) {
                   console.log('Incorrect username.');
                   return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' });
               } else if (password != user.password) {
                   console.log('Incorrect password');
                   return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
               } else {
                   console.log('ok');
                   done(null, user);
               }
            });

        }

    ));

};
```

This is the models/user.js

```
"use strict";

module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var User = sequelize.define("User", {
    email: DataTypes.STRING,
    password: DataTypes.STRING,
    token: DataTypes.STRING
  } 

  );

  return User;
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sequelize's `.then()` receives result only, errors should be handled by `.catch()` block. So the query will looks like this:

```
        User.findOne({where: {username: username}}).then(function(user) {
           if (!user) {
               console.log('Incorrect username.');
               return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' });
           } else if (password != user.password) {
               console.log('Incorrect password');
               return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
           } else {
               console.log('ok');
               done(null, user);
           }
        }).catch(function(err){
           done(err);
        });
```

Comment: Thanks! But I'm still getitng the same error. The user is being redirected to the signup form

Comment: This block should be used in login strategy, not signup. In signup strategy you should check username to be unique, then save user and call `done()` function with passing needed params